# convert string to specific format string

Tags: python

> How the input should be like:

aaabbcca

> How the output should be like:

a3b2c2a1

My attempt:

```
string = input()
ans = ""

i = 0
j=0
while i < len(string):
    num=1
    ans += string[i]
    j = i + 1 
    if j >= len(string): break
    while j < len(string):
        if string[i] == string[j]:
            num += 1
        else:
            ans += str(num)
            i = j
            break

print(ans)


# i = 0
# for i in range(len(string)):
#     num=0
#     ans += string[i]
#     for j in range(i,len(string)):
#         if string[i] == string[j]:
#             num +=1
#             i = j
#         else: break
#     ans += str(num)
    

# print(ans)
```

My problem: nothing is printed

how can i get this code right?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? A string matching problem?

Comment: You never increment `j`, so you get into an infinite loop with `while j<len(string)`.

Comment: i missed that thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to explore `groupby` from `itertools`.

For example:

```
def encode(data: str) -> str:
    return "".join(f"{x}{sum(1 for _ in y)}" for x, y in groupby(data))

print(encode("aaabbcca"))
```

Output:

```
a3b2c2a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Second loop is redundant for this case. You can simply take first char as a base case and with one loop you can do all you need.

```
raw_str = 'aaabbcca'

last_char = raw_str[0]
res = ''
count = 0
for i in range(len(raw_str)):
    if raw_str[i] == last_char:
        count +=1
    else:
        res += raw_str[i - 1] + str(count)
        last_char = raw_str[i]
        count = 1

# If there is only 1 different char at the end of the str, it will not call if
# so you need to check explicitly if the last char is equal to your lastly added one
if last_char != raw_str[-2]:
    res += last_char + str(count)
```

Comment: omg great thanks to you